# Alexa Skill C# Will not play Audio

Tags: c#, audio, alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa skill that I want to play a song on launch. I'm using VS2017 with the AWS Toolkit and an AWS Lambda function. I've configured and built my Alexa skill and published my Lambda function and verified with both the Alexa Console test and my Alexa Echo all of that is working.

When I change from returning text in my SkillResponse to returning an audio directive using AudioPlayerPlay(from the Alex.NET Nuget package) I get what appears to well formed and correct JSON, however the Alexa Console test says its an unsupported device and my Alexa Echo does nothing.

This is the JSON from the AWS Lambda test.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "shouldEndSession": true,
    "directives": [
      {
        "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
        "audioItem": {
          "stream": {
            "url": "https://music.amazon.com/my/albums/You+Get+What+You+Give/YOU+GET+WHAT+YOU+GIVE/ZAC+BROWN+BAND?ie=UTF8&albumAsin=B00438BTJ6&playNow=1&trackAsin=B004386MMU",
            "token": "scrumstartsong",
            "expectedPreviousToken": null,
            "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
          }
        },
        "type": "AudioPlayer.Play"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the entry from the Alexa Console test for the Directive:AudioPlayer.Play command

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "AudioPlayer",
        "name": "Play",
        "messageId": "d0c18d3c-2403-4f56-a059-67f3855f4e47",
        "dialogRequestId": "0bae3b83-21f6-47a3-ae7c-b13b9487e60e"
    },
    "payload": {
        "audioItem": {
            "audioItemId": "amzn1.as-ct.v1.ThirdPartySdkSpeechlet#ACRI#url#ACRI#{\"directedCustomerId\":\"amzn1.ask.account.AHGMQILIBZCL6YKVYSGTEOJGJ2B7I3FUTXBL7AZWBULBPMOA4CGW7JBRTO7AZXAWVLVDLEB4EP3XRPOZXAUVA64I66QCHGSZ5A3OK4GHP4TR6BOJVAEKXVGD7NTASS6AYD5RDCBS4JS3SH7EFGYBWS34F7TC7GFMDOWRICBA6EYYKISCVKURCUMFTSXXWZDXUVE7NG336KWDJHY\",\"modelKey\":\"amzn1.ask.skill.8e374b1d-05d8-4455-afc5-d701aed22b7d\",\"obfuscatedCustomerId\":\"A2JSZ6NNUSHRJJ\",\"token\":\"scrumstartsong\"}",
            "stream": {
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 0,
                "expiryTime": "2019-03-11T19:47:01+0000",
                "url": "https://music.amazon.com/my/albums/You+Get+What+You+Give/YOU+GET+WHAT+YOU+GIVE/ZAC+BROWN+BAND?ie=UTF8&albumAsin=B00438BTJ6&playNow=1&trackAsin=B004386MMU",
                "token": "amzn1.as-ct.v1.ThirdPartySdkSpeechlet#ACRI#url#ACRI#{\"directedCustomerId\":\"amzn1.ask.account.AHGMQILIBZCL6YKVYSGTEOJGJ2B7I3FUTXBL7AZWBULBPMOA4CGW7JBRTO7AZXAWVLVDLEB4EP3XRPOZXAUVA64I66QCHGSZ5A3OK4GHP4TR6BOJVAEKXVGD7NTASS6AYD5RDCBS4JS3SH7EFGYBWS34F7TC7GFMDOWRICBA6EYYKISCVKURCUMFTSXXWZDXUVE7NG336KWDJHY\",\"modelKey\":\"amzn1.ask.skill.8e374b1d-05d8-4455-afc5-d701aed22b7d\",\"obfuscatedCustomerId\":\"A2JSZ6NNUSHRJJ\",\"token\":\"scrumstartsong\"}"
            }
        },
        "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL"
    }
}
```

I've tried different (and no) values for the token.

I have verified I have access to the song on my Echo by having Alexa play it.

Answer (score 0):

My sense is that there is no issues on your code! I fair to date, Audio Player directives are not supported on the Alexa developer console simulator :(

This is documented at https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#requests :

See also my point here: [Alexa Skill AudioPlayer: Console test Support poor support/bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511999/alexa-skill-audioplayer-console-test-support-poor-support-bugs)