# Alexa Skill AudioPlayer: Console test Support poor support/bugs

Tags: api, alexa-skills-kit, audio-player, alexa-voice-service

I'm developing a skill to play my own music.

I have troubles with AudioPlayer with the developer console test environment ( https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask/test/ ). Two questions:

**1. AudioPlayer Built-in Intents doesn't run as expected (test simulator bug?)**

> Alexa, play mymusicsSkill
>
> playing Wanderer track 1: Antelao Adrift

---

> Alexa, next
>
> What would you like to play next?

---

> Ask mymusicSkill next
>
> intent: next

---

See also screenshot:
[image]

BTW, my code:

```
  'AMAZON.NextIntent': function () {
    this.response.speak('intent: next')
    this.emit(':responseReady')
  },
```

So the expected behaviour, also following this documentation: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html

is that Alexa, next would fire the AMAZON.NextIntent of my skill, but it doesn't. That's a bug, in my opinion.

**2. AudioPlayer not (yet) supported on test simulator?**

I know that audio streaming is not supported on the console test simulator (See also my previous question: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/143902/when-test-simulator-will-support-audioplayer-direc.html ). Because I can't own a physical Echo (I'm from Italy and Amazon deny to sell my an echo to an italian address ), there is any way to test my skill using audio streams?

NOTE/SUGGESTION to improve the web test simulator:

even if there are problems to stream audio to the web test simulator, a workaround could be to visualize a message info, showing on the GUI that streaming is active (the play is active, etc.)...

Any idea?

Thanks
giorgio